# optimal buffer size for reading file in C

Tags: c, io

I have to read large files in C using `read` function. I was just wondering if it makes any difference what buffer size we keep in terms of performance. The file sizes may reach till tens of GB.

Comment: Of course buffer size matters, but "optimal" depends.

Comment: The larger the better, within reason.  And there will be some small advantage to using a buffer size that's a power of two (or at least a multiple of 512).

Comment: @HotLicks can you explain about why `512`

Comment: If you're on a Posix system, `fstat` tells you what size to use (`st_blksize`). Whether the number it tells you really is optimal is another matter, what it actually is is the lower bound below which the implementer is pretty sure I/O will be significantly sub-optimal. When you test, you'll probably find that this size gives you *most* of the gain available from larger buffers, but you can still gain a little performance if you multiply it by a smallish number.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam -- Sector size.  Most hard drives use a sector size of at least 512 (ranging up to 4096 and maybe larger in some brands).  The sector size will (almost) always be a power of 2, though.  If you don't issue reads on a sector boundary the drive will have to throw away some bytes it reads (and it really gets ugly if you don't write on a sector boundary).

Answer (score 10):

Short version.
It depends. On x86 buffer size of 4096 bytes is a good start (one [page size](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sysconf.3.html) and also [Advanced Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format) block size).

Longer version.
In UNIX it depends on kernel, libc, filesystem, hardware, etc. Not only on versions and compilation options but also on run-time tunables(e.g read ahead setup).

DIY.
Test it! See [Advanced Programing in UNIX Environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321525949) Chapter 3.9 "I/O Efficiency" for straightforward way of determining the best read-write buffer size for one particular system.

Answer (score 0):

First: for sure, a multiple of disk logical/physical sector size, something you can check by using hdparm. This is the same

Hint: the libc's `fopen(3)`, `fread(3)`, `fwrite(3)`, etc functions already do some good buffering for you.

Another hint: if you don't need to stream the whole file, but to randomly access parts of it, you could try `mmap()`ing it.

Comment: OS also does plenty of buffering even with `open|read|write` (page cache + readahead) if not instructed otherwise (`O_DIRECT`/`O_SYNC`)